# ArcGIS Desktop with Database Connections: Can not display coordinates from a view if aliases are used

Tags: arcmap, sql, sql-view, alias

The view `Locations_View` created in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is accessible in an ArcGIS Desktop project by `Database Connections`. Its numerical fields `PT_XCOOR` and `PT_YCOOR` are usable in the `Display XY Data` menu to plot points. However, if aliases are given for these fields (e.g. `X-Coordinate` and `Y-Coordinate`) the points won't be plot anymore although the aliases are properly viewable and selectable in the `Display XY Data` menu. No error or warning message appears. What has to be done in order to use aliases to plot points?

Technical data:

- SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) SQL Server, version 14.0.2027.2
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: version 15.0.18206.0
- ArcGIS Desktop: version 10.8.2

[image: Left: fields without aliases, Right: fields with aliases]

Comment: Hyphens are not standard SQL-compliant identifier characters (only alpha in first char and alphanumeric or underscore in the remaining chars). It is not possible for ArcGIS to reference a field with a non-conformant name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vince's comment and [Paulj's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements) as well as [Bonk's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917196/meaning-of-square-brackets-in-ms-sql-table-designer) cases lead to the answer:

An alias defined in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) can get used for Database Connection in ArcGIS Desktop only if it

1. is not a reserved keyword (e.g. index, order etc.), and
2. does not contain special characters such as a space or hyphen.

A simple feature for identification for a usable alias is, that the alias is not automatically put into square brackets [] by SSMS. In the given example, the aliases then should be e.g. `Pt_Index`, `XCoordinate` and `YCoordinate`.